# Is there are query to get all the keywords inside a category in Taxonomy Using content delivery graphql api

Tags: content-delivery, graphql, sites-9.6

Is there a graqhql CD query to get all the keywords inside a category in Taxonomy.

I see an endpoint, but it doesn't serve my purpose: `keyword(namespaceId: Int!, publicationId: Int!, categoryId: Int!, keywordId: Int!, contextData: [InputClaimValue]):`

Currently I am saving the key/value pairs in client application. so instead of saving in the client application.

I would like to query it using GraphQL Public Content API.

Comment: Arjun , Can you share which version of tridon you are using

Comment: I am using version 9.6

Answer (score 1):

We can get the category and keywords list using GraphiQL APIs in many ways.

**Option 1:**
This approach retrieves all categories and keywords in a single query, providing a comprehensive view of the taxonomy hierarchy. However, be cautious about the potential performance impact, especially in environments with a large number of categories and keywords.

```
{
  categories(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 10) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        itemType
        itemId
        description
        key
        title
        totalRelatedItems
        children {
          edges {
            node {
              ...KeywordFieldsLevel1
              children {
                edges {
                  node {
                    ...KeywordFieldsLevel1
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment KeywordFieldsLevel2 on Keyword {
  title
  description
  itemId
  key
  hasChildren
}

fragment KeywordFieldsLevel1 on Keyword {
  title
  key
  description
  hasChildren
  itemId
  children {
    edges {
      node {
        ...KeywordFieldsLevel2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Option 2:** The advantage of using this approach it is more targeted, allowing you to fetch specific categories and their first-level keywords individually. This can improve performance when you only need information about a subset of the taxonomy.

```
query GetCountryKeywords {
  k1: keyword(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 10, categoryId: 46, keywordId: 1066) {
    ...ParentKeyword
  }
  k2: keyword(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 10, categoryId: 46, keywordId: 2430) {
    ...ParentKeyword
  }
  k3: keyword(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 10, categoryId: 46, keywordId: 2433) {
    ...ParentKeyword
  }
  k4: keyword(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 10, categoryId: 46, keywordId: 2446) {
    ...ParentKeyword
  }
  k5: keyword(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 10, categoryId: 46, keywordId: 2449) {
    ...ParentKeyword
  }
}

fragment ParentKeyword on Keyword {
  id
  itemType
  itemId
  description
  key
  title
  hasChildren
  children {
    edges {
      node {
        ...KeywordFieldsLevel1
        children {
          edges {
            node {
              ...KeywordFieldsLevel1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment KeywordFieldsLevel2 on Keyword {
  title
  description
  itemId
  key
  hasChildren
  customMetas {
    edges {
      node {
        key
        value
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment KeywordFieldsLevel1 on Keyword {
  title
  key
  description
  hasChildren
  itemId
  children {
    edges {
      node {
        ...KeywordFieldsLevel2
      }
    }
  }
  customMetas {
    edges {
      node {
        key
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.